# Javascript (node.js) Math.floor returning long decimal values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't seem to get a nice number rounded to the nearest hundredth (ie. 12.57 instead of 12.57000000008).

```
var example = {
    user : "John",
    dollars: 12.57
};

setInterval( function() {
    example.dollars += (parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*2000 + 500)) / 100);
    console.log(example.dollars);
}, 1000);
```

I keep getting values like:
15.20000000008
88.54000000007
86.36000000008

Am I setting something wrong in my Math function?

Note:  This is in node.js

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try isolating the number to the hundredth place. ie `[86.36]000000008`

```
var example = {
    user : "John",
    dollars: 12.57
};

setInterval(function() {
    var s, final;
    example.dollars += (parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000 + 500)) / 100);

    s = example.dollars + .005 + '',
    final = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('.') + 3); 
    console.log(final);
}, 1000);
```

All we are doing is **removing everything after the hundredth decimal place.** in order to do that we need to find the decimal place so we can find the hundredth decimal value per say.  First we must convert the number into a string, `+ ''` or you can use the `toString()` function. then we use `indexOf('.')` to find the decimal placement and finally we  count three places over. that will get you the number to the hundredth place, without the long decimal values.

Examples:
 input: `12.57000000008` output: `12.57`

 input: `15.20000000008` output: `15.20`

[Working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/SSdhK/1)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, but it shows 18.4 instead of 18.40 How can this be fixed?

Comment: `+ .005` rounds to the nearest hundredth. My last edit should be your final code

Answer (score 2):

Javascript numbers are floating point numbers.  They should not be relied upon for precision decimal operations.

For instance you can enter this into a js console

```
.1 + .2 //0.30000000000000004
```

Generally you can count on integer mathematics accurately,and if you need more control on decimal accuracy, you can look into libraries like [this one](https://github.com/sjkaliski/numbers.js) which lets you set error bounds on your numbers, or make a call to an external library written in a language with better handling of number types.

More libraries for accurate JS decimal math:

- https://npmjs.org/package/decimal
- https://github.com/iriscouch/bigdecimal.js

Comment: `1 + .2` returns `1.2`. I think you meant `0.1 + 0.2` :)

Comment: This is the best answer for NodeJS.  the Decimal package fixed me right up.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to support modern browsers, the [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method is the best choice. It takes an argument representing the number of decimal places to round to and returns a `String`.

```
example.dollars.toFixed(2); // returns "12.57"
```

Comment: If you do need to support older browsers, you can use `toFixed` with [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim).

Comment: not supported by nodejs